# Which of the following 3 ways to load JSON is the most efficient?

Tags: javascript, json

Out of these 3 ways to load JSON, which one is the most efficient that most web developers use?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

OR

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  jsonp: "callback",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data) {
  }
});
```

OR

```
$getJSON("POST/GET","url");
```

Comment: 1 is most efficient. 2/3 is most used and is equal

Comment: So Jonas can you tell me which will decrease my lag. I mean loading speed;;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited the title so that it's shorter and focused on the issue (no need to write "I want to know", it is evident) and specified that you're asking about methods to load JSON (this way people are more attracted to it since they know if it's their topic; and it is more valuable for those who search at SO). I've also made some formatting improvements for the code to be more readable and removed CAPS LOCK. Hope you do so yourself in your next question :) Best regards

Comment: How do you define *efficient*?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your issue?

Comment: The time spent is not in executing the written code, but in the transfer over the net (request/response) and server time to produce the response.

Comment: All of these do effectively the same thing and none of them is inherently faster from a fetching perspective. That's entirely up to how slow your HTTP or HTTPS response is.

Comment: The second one doesn't work at all, since it tries to load a JSONP script not a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've defined 'efficiency' as 'lag', they're all the same, as they all perform the same HTTP request to the server and have the same connection speed.